Should I replace fiberglass bats in my basement with rigid foam insulation?
I am doing some remodeling in my finished basement. I live in Zone 4a, and my basement walls are all filled with fiberglass bats against painted concrete block. The studs appear to be right against the block. I'd like to "do things right" when I remodel, but I don't want to be a fool by wasting money, either. My question is, is it worthwhile to replace the fiberglass bats with another form of insulation? As I understand it rigid foam is most useful in a basement when it is behind the studs themselves and against the concrete wall. If I cut down rigid foam and add it in the stud bays will it be any better than the fiberglass? And if so, how much better? Enough to rip out and replace all of my current insulation? I understand that fiberglass can wick moisture and rigid foam is not prone to this.

The rigid foam is placed first so that acts as a thermal break to the wood studs placed against it, increasing the overall insulating value of the stud wall.
Expanded Polystyrene board has an R value of 4 per inch. A 2 x 4 stud wall with R 12 fiberglass batts has about an R 8 value measured across the entire wall. Used in combination, the wall be closer to R 12-14.
In my opinion, the increase in performance across the entire wall is not worth the effort in a remodel unless the nature of the remodel is such that the change affects an entire wall without making the change obvious. You have nothing to lose.
